# Is React Native suitable for building an OpenGL-accelerated 2D-game?

Tags: react-native, 2d-games, side-scroller

Say I wanted to build something like a 2D side-scroller game. Would React Native be suitable performance-wise? E.g., can I use OpenGL-acceleration for it? Or would it probably be slower than just using WebGL and HTML5?

Researched some more and came up with this information:

Apparently there is a GLView which holds a WebGL context:
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/gl-view.html

On that page it says this:

> Any WebGL-supporting library that expects a WebGLRenderingContext
>   could be used. Some times such libraries assume a web JavaScript
>   context (such as assuming document). Usually this is for resource
>   loading or event handling, with the main rendering logic still only
>   using pure WebGL. So these libraries can usually still be used with a
>   couple workarounds. The Expo-specific integrations above include
>   workarounds for some popular libraries.

Also a Twitter comment from Expo which mentions 'games' specifically:

```
Expo Graphics gives you the power of GL combined with Expo+React Native. It 
is the foundation for image filters, games, and special effects.
```

And there should be a demo here:
https://github.com/gre/gl-react

Not much projects listed there which use React Native to build a game. Still, there being a WebGL context interface to a native OpenGL acceleration gives rise to hope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used [react-native-webgl](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webgl) to build a [minesweeper game](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.mobilefront.bombsweeper). This library has provided the performance gain I needed to render a 16x30 grid of cells with quick transitions from one state to another. In some circumstances the game needs to re-render dozens or even hundreds of cells at once. Default React Native renderer is not fast enough to do that without user noticing the delay.

Note that while react-native-webgl solves the performance problem, it requires you to write low level code such as creating shaders, manage the vertices etc. And I haven't found libraries built on top of react-native-webgl that would work for my task.

So if you really need or want to use React Native for your game, use react-native-webgl or GLView for Expo. Otherwise use a different technology like Unity.

You can find the source code of my game [here](https://github.com/armenbadalyan/minesweeper-reactnative).

Comment: Where you able to make an iOS version?

Comment: Yes, but it is not released yet. See this [branch](https://github.com/armenbadalyan/minesweeper-reactnative/tree/feature/ios-support).